# d3.js choropleth map --How do I map more than one property from CSV to JSON, so I can use it in a tooltip?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I have a choropleth map that I've built with d3.js. I'm mapping the 'Total_Score' property in my data.csv to the 'id' property in my JSON file, and I'm using that score to color the states. I'm also showing it on mouseover with a tooltip.

However, I'd like to be able to show the other properties that are in my CSV file, too. There are four others -- "rank", "first", "second" and "third". Do I have to create a map for each of these, too? I've never mapped more than one, so any guidance or example would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

[Here is a plunker for reference.](http://plnkr.co/edit/skU8jNUkdc0FZJl4dEWK?p=preview)

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Worst Drivers</title>
            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
            <script src="d3.tip.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
                body{
                    background:#333;
                    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                    font-size:13px;
                    color:#fff;
                    padding:0px;
                    margin:0px;
                }
                h1{
                    margin:50px 0px 0px;
                    text-align:center;
                    font-size:30px;
                    font-weight:normal;
                }
                h2{
                    margin:0px;
                    padding:0px;
                }
                h4{
                    font-size:16px;
                }
                a{
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #2bbe8c;
                }
                #panel{
                    background:#fff;
                    color:#111;
                    width:27%;
                    height:100%;
                    float:right;
                    padding:3%;
                }
                #map{
                    width:66%;
                    float:left;
                }
                .sources{
                    font-size:12px;
                }
                .d3-tip{
                    background:#000;
                    opacity:.7;
                    padding:20px;
                    border-radius:3px;
                }
                .statename{
                    font-size:16px;
                }
                .mainno{
                    font-size:14px;
                }
                #legend{
                    position:absolute;
                    width:66%;
                    height:20px;
                }
                #legendinner{
                    margin:0 auto;
                    position:relative;
                    width:245px;
                }
                .legendleft{
                    width:50px;
                    float:left;
                    margin:0px;
                }
                .legendright{
                    width:50px;
                    float:right;
                    text-align:right;
                    margin:0px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="map">
                    <div id="legend">
                        <div id="legendinner">
                            <svg width="250" height="15">
                                <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="10" fill="#041e47"></rect>
                                <rect x="50" y="0" width="50" height="10" fill="#063685"></rect>
                                <rect x="100" y="0" width="50" height="10" fill="#0449bb"></rect>
                                <rect x="150" y="0" width="50" height="10" fill="#055ced"></rect>
                                <rect x="200" y="0" width="50" height="10" fill="#5092ff"></rect>
                            </svg>
                            <p class="legendleft">Most</p>
                            <p class="legendright">Least</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                //Width and height
                var w = Math.max(window.innerWidth) / 3 *2;
                var h = Math.max(window.innerHeight) - 100;

                //Create SVG element
                map  = d3.select("#map")
                         .append("svg")
                                 .attr("id", "usstates")
                         .attr("width",  w)
                         .attr("height", h);

          var maph = document.getElementById('usstates').clientHeight;

                d3.select("#legend")
                .style("top", maph + 150 + "px");

                //Define map projection
                var p = d3.geo.albersUsa()
                        .translate([w/2, h/2])
                        .scale([1000]);

                //Define path generator
                var path = d3.geo.path()
                        .projection(p);



              //load the geoJSON file for drawing the map
                d3.json("states.json", function(error, states) {

                    var newDict = {}; //mapping for choropleth
                    var tip = d3.tip()
                            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
                            .offset([40, 0])
                            .html(function(d,i) { 
                                return "<span class='statename'>" + d.properties.name + "</span>" + 
                                "<hr/>" +
                                "<span class='mainno'>Total Score: " + newDict[d.id] + 
                                "<br/>rank: </span>" +
                                "<hr/>" + 
                                "First: " +
                                "<br/>Second: " +
                                "<br/>Third: " ;
                            })

                    var mapstates = map.append("svg:g")
                            .attr("id", "states")
                            .style("fill", "#dedee0")
                            .style("stroke", "#aaa")
                            .style("stroke-width", .5);

                            mapstates.call(tip);

                    mapstates
                                    .selectAll("path")
                                    .data(states.features)
                                .enter().append("path")
                                .attr("d", path);

                        d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

                            data.forEach(function(d){
                              d.rank = + d.rank;
                                d.Total_Score   = +d.Total_Score;
                              newDict[d.id] = +d.Total_Score;
                            });

                            var minValue = d3.min(data, function(d,data) { return d.Total_Score; });
                            var maxValue = d3.max(data, function(d,data) { return d.Total_Score; });

                            //Quantize scale for map
                            var color = d3.scale.quantize()
                                    .domain([minValue, maxValue])
                                    .range(["#041e47", "#063685", "#0449bb", "#055ced", "#5092ff"]);



                            mapstates
                                            .selectAll("path")
                                        .attr("d", path)
                                            .on('mouseover', function(d) {

                                               d3.select(this).style('fill-opacity', .75);
                                            })
                                            .on('mouseout', function(d){
                                                d3.select(this).style("fill-opacity", 1);
                                            })
                                            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                                            .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
                                            .attr("class", function(d){return newDict[d.id];})
                                            .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(newDict[d.id]); })
                                            .text("heyo");

                            mapstates.selectAll("text")
                                            .data(states.features)
                                            .enter()
                                            .append("text")
                                            .html(function(d){
                                                 return d.properties.abbr + ": " + newDict[d.id] ;
                                            })
                                            .attr("x", function(d){
                                                return path.centroid(d)[0];
                                            })
                                            .attr("y", function(d){
                                                 return  path.centroid(d)[1];
                                            })
                                            .attr("text-anchor","middle")
                                            .attr('font-size',11)
                                            .attr('font-weight', 'normal');

                        }); //close csv
                }); // close json

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

data.csv file:

```
"State","id","first","second","third","TotalScore","rank"
    "Alabama",1,15,24,29,113,18
    "Alaska",2,22,51,50,195,49
    "Arizona",4,14,28,41,109,14
    "Arkansas",5,5,21,43,141,28
    "California",6,42,26,39,146,33
    "Colorado",8,33,4,24,101,11
    "Connecticut",9,48,44,9,185,47
    "Delaware",10,21,31,12,74,7
    "District of Columbia",11,51,8,32,139,27
    "Florida",12,19,29,30,131,24
    "Georgia",13,28,11,46,147,34
    "Hawaii",15,20,33,6,70,5
    "Idaho",16,27,20,36,152,38
    "Illinois",17,39,39,10,125,22
    "Indiana",18,36,19,34,165,42
    "Iowa",19,25,38,48,205,50
    "Kansas",20,17,15,47,151,37
    "Kentucky",21,6,2,49,131,24
    "Louisiana",22,7,5,19,71,6
    "Maine",23,26,10,17,103,12
    "Maryland",24,41,50,18,141,28
    "Massachusetts",25,50,37,8,156,39
    "Michigan",26,37,42,37,179,45
    "Minnesota",27,49,34,35,205,50
    "Mississippi",28,8,12,26,111,17
    "Missouri",29,24,18,13,91,10
    "Montana",30,3,6,1,59,2
    "Nebraska",31,29,16,7,141,28
    "Nevada",32,30,14,14,79,8
    "New Hampshire",33,43,46,33,190,48
    "New Jersey",34,46,43,21,160,40
    "New Mexico",35,11,27,42,109,14
    "New York",36,40,36,20,143,31
    "North Carolina",37,23,35,23,109,14
    "North Dakota",38,4,3,2,66,4
    "Ohio",39,35,22,15,135,26
    "Oklahoma",40,9,1,31,87,9
    "Oregon",41,34,49,45,184,46
    "Pennsylvania",42,18,32,25,105,13
    "Rhode Island",44,44,48,4,147,34
    "South Carolina",45,1,30,3,54,1
    "South Dakota",46,10,7,11,114,20
    "Tennessee",47,13,25,27,143,31
    "Texas",48,12,23,5,63,3
    "Utah",49,45,9,51,169,44
    "Vermont",50,31,13,40,113,18
    "Virginia",51,38,40,38,163,41
    "Washington",53,47,47,22,165,42
    "West Virginia",54,2,45,44,116,21
    "Wisconsin",55,32,17,16,130,23
    "Wyoming",56,16,41,28,149,36
```

(I can't paste the states.json file here because it exceeds the allowed body size for posts, but you can see it if you go to the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/skU8jNUkdc0FZJl4dEWK?p=preview).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create objects and put them in your newDict. Any other collection would work as well.

below is the code that adds a new object with rank and score attributes.

```
data.forEach(function(d){
  d.rank = d.rank;
  d.Total_Score = d.Total_Score;
  newDict[d.id] = {rank:d.rank, score:d.Total_Score};
});
```

These can then be used like a normal object.

```
mapstates
    .selectAll("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
        d3.select(this).style('fill-opacity', .75);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d){
        d3.select(this).style("fill-opacity", 1);
    })
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
    .attr("class", function(d){return newDict[d.id];})
    attr("fill", function(d) { return color(newDict[d.id].score); });
```

Adding any number of values is a simple addition to the data.forEach closure.

[Here's my fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/xKrM3XxgLL39wzkag9Yj) of your plunker with some of the changes implemented.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for being such a huge help!